# In Perl, how can I parse space delimited data which also include a field with spaces?

Tags: perl, scripting

I got the error "Use of uninitialized value in subroutine entry at ./test.pl line 20." when I run the below code.

### INPUT

```
2015-05-01      abc     serv1   X       View impl details        34      33      2       0       1       0       4552    3312    0       72      0       0       0       0       0       0       0
       0       1       576     3       1       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0.0     0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
       0       1       381     671     1
2015-05-01      def   serv2   X       Assessment for next exam preview  22      22      0       0       1       0       1195    3577    0       3053    0       0       0       2       2       0
       0       0       26      163     10      2       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0.0     0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
       0       0       12      5       21      1
```

### OUTPUT

The first 4 fields separated by spaces have to be printed as it is. However, as you can see ,5th field on wards, there can be any number of space separated words. I want to club them all together as 5th field until a number is found as the next field. In the above sample input, I want "View impl details" as 5th field instead of "view" as 5th,"impl" as 6th and details as 7th fields. The same goes with 2nd row of data. I would like "Assessment for next exam preview" to appear as 5th field & the rest as their own fields.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use POSIX;

my $i_file='../out/test.out';
my $o_file='../sql/test.out';

my $text_cont="";

open (FILE, $i_file) or die "Could not read from $i_file, program halting.";
    while(<FILE>) {
        (my $fl_1, my $fl_2, my $fl_3, my $fl_4, my @subfields) = split;
        my @join_fields;

        my $l=0;
        for (my $k=5; $k <= 53; $k++) {
            $join_fields[$l] = "";

            if(isdigit($subfields[$k])) {
                $join_fields[$l] = $subfields[$k];
                $l = $l + 1;
            }
            else {
                $join_fields[$l] = $join_fields[$l] . $subfields[$k];
            }
        }
    }
close FILE;
```

I want to read thousands of lines from a file each line containing more than 50 fields separated by space. I'm reading each line, splitting the data by space as delimiter to start with. From the 5th field on wards, until I get a field with digits, I want to append the fields to the 5th field. Then finally print out the output.

I'm new to Perl. My understanding of the error is that it is unable to find definition for "isdigit". However, looking at few solutions on the internet, I used the POSIX package. It doesn't seem to help. Could someone please help me achieve my requirement?

### UPDATED SCRIPT

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $i_file='../out/test.out';
my $o_file='../sql/test.sql';

my $text_cont=" ";

open (FILE, $i_file) or die "Could not read from $i_file, program halting.";
    while(<FILE>) {
        (my $fl_1, my $fl_2, my $fl_3, my $fl_4, my @subfields) = split;
        my @join_fields;

        my $l=0;
        foreach my $k_val ( @subfields ) {
            #$join_fields[$l] = "";
            if ($k_val ne " ") {
                if ( $k_val =~ m/^\d+$/ ) {
                    $join_fields[$l] = $k_val;
                    $l = $l ++;
                }
                else {
                    my $temp = $join_fields[$l];
                    my $new_val = $temp.$k_val;
                    $join_fields[$l] = $new_val;
                }
                $text_cont = $text_cont."$join_fields[0]";
            }
        }
    }
close FILE;

open STDOUT, ">", $o_file or die "$0: open: $!";
    print "$text_cont";
close STDOUT;
```

Comment: Please provide sample file input and output.

Comment: Hello Arunesh. I've updated the question with the input & output details.

Comment: The problem is not that Perl can't find a definition for `isdigit`. It's that you are passing `isdigit` a value that is undefined. So one of the `$subfields[$k]` values that you have is undefined.

Comment: You are right Dave. Hmm, I'm now struggling to implement this.

Comment: Hello Dave & Arunesh - I've updated the script as per Sobrique's comments. I get a different error now. Could you please help me understand & fix it please? I've updated the new script as "UPDATED SCRIPT" int he question area

Comment: I see that your copy & paste might have mangled original data lines (e.g. by inserting line-breaks). Is it possible that these fields are actually fixed-width but due to something going wrong in your copy & paste, they appear to to be?

Comment: `$l = $l++` makes me uncomfortable.

Comment: @JimDavis Especially since `$l++` or `$l += 1` is probably what the OP wants. OP: Translated to words, `$l = $l++` can be read as "assign `$l` to `$l` and then increment `$l`." If the compiler interprets your statement that way, all you have created is a redundancy. However, at least one of my `perl`s gives: `$ perl -wE '$l = 2; $l = $l++; say $l'` ⏎ `$ 2` ***Ouch!*** Also, given that `$1` is a legal variable in Perl, using `$l` is needlessly confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without your source information, I can't tell for sure, but  think you probably have a fence post error here:

```
(my $fl_1, my $fl_2, my $fl_3, my $fl_4, my @subfields) = split;

for (my $k=5; $k <= 53; $k++) {
            if(isdigit($subfields[$k])) {
```

You're iterating @subfields from 5 to 53. But the first 'subfield' field is the '4th' field in your list. Unless you really mean from field `9-57`.

I don't think you do, because even if you take out the 'wrapping' on your sample lines - your 'subfields' only have 51 elements. This is the source of your problem.

You should also note though that `split` splits on any whitespace. 
Therefore you get `@subfields` containing:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'View',
          'impl',
          'details',
          '34',
          '33',
          '2',
```

But I'd suggest you probably don't want to do it this way anyway - you only use `$k` to index `@subfields`.

So why not instead:

```
foreach my $k_val ( @subfields ) { 
    if ( isdigit $k_val ) { 
         # etc... 
    }
}
```

But you're also right - I get a warning that `isdigit` is deprecated:

> Deprecated function whose use raises a warning, and which is slated to be removed in a future Perl version. It is very similar to matching against qr/ ^ [[:digit:]]+ $ /x , which you should convert to use instead.

There's a variety of ways to do something similar - I would suggest you might want:

```
if ( $k_val =~ m/^\d+$/ ) {
```

Which will use regular expressions to check that `$k_val` is only numeric (1 or more numeric chars).

Comment: Hello Sobrique - Many thanks for this. I will test this solution. I've updated the question too with input & output details

Comment: Hello Sobrique, - I updated the script. I'm testing by appending just the $join_fields[0]". However, it's complaining about the Use of uninitialized value $temp in concatenation (.) or string at ./test.pl line 25. Could you please help me get this right :-( I've updated the question with "UPDATED SCRIPT"

Comment: Don't forget you can use `split` with a limit. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31702053/100754).

Comment: Hello Sobrique - Thank you heaps.  You've been of immense help

Answer (score 3):

If these are indeed fixed-width fields that got mangled during copy & paste, you should use `unpack`. Otherwise, you can take advantage of the fact that you can [specify a limit  when using `split`](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#split-PATTERN-EXPR-LIMIT):

> If `LIMIT` is specified and positive, it represents the maximum number of fields into which the `EXPR` may be split; in other words, `LIMIT` is one greater than the maximum number of times `EXPR` may be split.

The original wording of the question seemed to imply that the fifth field, called `$msg` below, never contained digits. In light of OP's comment showing the presence of at least one row where the field contains the text `WD25`, I am updating the pattern below to be more permissive for the text in this field.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $i_file = 'userpf.input';

open my $IN, '<', $i_file
    or die "Cannot open '$i_file': $!";

my @data;

while (my $line = <$IN>) {
    next unless $line =~ /\S/;
    my ($date, $type, $serv, $flag, $rest) = split ' ', $line, 5;
    my ($msg, $fields) = ($rest =~ /^ (.+?) \s+ ([0-9] .+) /x);
    push @data, [ $date, $type, $serv, $flag, $msg, split(' ', $fields) ];
}

for my $x (@data) {
    print "'$_'\n" for @$x;
}
```

I took the liberty of giving names to the initial fields.

Comment: Hello Sinan - Brilliant. Thankyou very much. I get the error, "Use of uninitialized value $fields in split at ./test.pl line 17, <$IN> line xxxxx". Please could you help fix this?

Comment: Hello Sinan - I managed to figure that out. Thank you. In one of the lines of input, the input lines has a string "N/A: WD25 : Delta pro seventeen under" in the 5th field. For this, the script prints just ": Delta pro seventeen under".  Should the code not interpret this as text & print the whole string out?

Comment: Sinan - Thank you heaps.  You've been of immense help

Answer (score 1):

As per I understood your requirement I have modified your script. I have modified the input record separator [`$/`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Variables-related-to-filehandles) from `\n` to `2015`, as your required string which is to be processed is separated by newline, Although the solution is quite hackish, But it will work:

I will suggest you to check [File::Stream](http://search.cpan.org/~smueller/File-Stream-2.30/lib/File/Stream.pm) to make input record separator `$/` a regex i.e if value is other than `2015` or something.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

local $/="2015"; # set input record separator as 2015
open my $fh, '<','file' or die "unable to open file: $! \n";
my @subfields;
my $junk=<$fh>; # remove first one
while(<$fh>){
  chomp;  # remove 2015 from last
  $_= $junk.$_; # concatenate 2015 at begining of $_
  (my $fl_1, my $fl_2, my $fl_3, my $fl_4, my @subfields) = split;
    my @join_fields; 
    my $new_val="";
     foreach my $k_val ( @subfields ) {
      if ( $k_val =~ m/^\d+(.\d+)?$/ ) {
            push(@join_fields,$k_val);   
        }
      else{
          $new_val .= $k_val;
       }
    }

   push(@join_fields,$new_val);
   my $fl_5 = pop @join_fields; # pop out your fifth field here
   print "$fl_1 $fl_2 $fl_3 $fl_4 $fl_5 @join_fields \n";

}
close($fh);
```

Comment: Hello Arunesh - Many thanks. However, I get the below errors - readline() on unopened filehandle DATA at ./test.pl line 13.
readline() on unopened filehandle DATA at ./test.pl line 14. Is this beacuse the file isn't opened? I did try opening file but I can't figure out if the the while <FILE> i still required. Could you please update the code & show me how to open & close file in this particular case?

Comment: Hello Arunesh - Many thanks for your time. It still doesn't work fully. If a line has 2015 as one of the values, it seems to cut off all values from 2015 till the end of the line to a new line. Please could you help? Here's an example 

LINE-1 => 2015-06-01,avbf,adfg,X,profile update by module8,181 ,178 ,11 ,0 ,34 ,108 ,131535 ,177479 ,0 ,1005 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0

LINE-2 => 2015,1835,455,0,,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0.0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,5 ,185 ,405 ,15

These should both be on the same line

Comment: Arunesh - Thank you heaps.  You've been of immense help